# Unusual "Illegal Forward Referance" Java Compile error

Tags: java, reference

I'm developing a small program which shows the screen co-ordinates of the mouse pointer in real time, displaying the co-ordinates in the format: "[x;y]"

Here is a small piece of code which for some reason returns an Illegal forward reference error:

```
while(1=1)
{
    mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    xy = mouse.getLocation();
    int x1 = xy.x;
    int y1 = xy.y;
    String a = "["+x1+";"+y1+"]";
    jlbl.setText(a);
}
```

'mouse' is a PointerInfo object and 'xy' is a Point object which have been declared and have their relevant packages imported. 
The line "jlbl.setText(""+a);" gives the error, where 'jlbl' is a jLabel declared by NetBeans automatically.

Any reson to why this is happening?

Thanks so much to all in advance, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: My appologies for the incorrect code formatting :(

Comment: The "1=1" part will give another compile-time error...

Comment: If an exception is thrown show the stacktrace and indicate what line in your source it corresponds to.  Also I think (1=1) indicates typing instead of copying, please always show the exact source giving the problem.

Comment: In addition to the exact code, please also post the exact error message.

Comment: @Jarod, if you really wanted constant boolean you could have just typed "while(true)". But "1=1" is not even a correct expression, it is an assignment, unlike "1==1". Not that using either of these makes sense.

Comment: By mousing over the line "jlbl.setText(a);"in NetBeans, it showed "Illegal forward reference" exactly. The Stacktrace however did not show this, but rather "illegal start of type" to the line "jlbl.setText(a);" as well as "while(1=1)"

Comment: Thanks for that, my coding has become a bit rusty, so I've decided to exercise the "grey-matter" a bit.

Comment: hmm, if I replace `1=1` with `true` and just print the string `a`, this code compiles and works fine.

Comment: @Jarod it seems you have missed @Jon 's comment

Answer (score 0):

Promoting OP's comment to answer ...

Ah, by replacing the "1=1" with a boolean variable initialised as "true" when the program starts and "false" before it ends fixed that problem. I've also updated my JDK and JRE to the new JDK6 Update 23 and seems to be working fine. A bug maybe?